# Why was $\tan\theta$ used?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

In reference to $(a)$, I do not understand why the tan ratio was used? Tan is $\frac{Opposite} {Adjacent}$ . Where should I be looking at to be able to determine the $\frac{Opposite} {Adjacent}$? Confused please help!!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Note that tan is opposite over adjacent.

Comment: tan=opposite/adjacent

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I am aware tan is opposite / adjacent. Can't work it out still why? Is it because we are WANTING to find that side, so we put it in the calculations?

Comment: @Economist:  You can edit your Question, to correct the typo.

Comment: Fixed the mistake. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\tan$ is opposite over adjacent. You are getting confused with $\sin$, which is opposite over hypotenuse.

In general, the trick is to pick three things, two of which you know, and plug them into one of the three equations: $\sin=\frac{Opp}{Hyp}$, $\cos=\frac{Adj}{Hyp}$ and $\tan=\frac{Opp}{Adj}$. You then rearrange your equation to find the unknown.

Here, consider the angle at $P$, which is $55^{\circ}$. It has $\operatorname{Opposite}=GC$ and $\operatorname{Adjacent}=PG=9000$. Hence, $\tan 55^{\circ}=\frac{Opp}{Adj}=\frac{GC}{9000}$...

We *could* have chosen the angle at $C$. This has $\operatorname{Opposite}=PG=9000$ and $\operatorname{Adjacent}=GC$. Hence, $\tan 35^{\circ}=\frac{Opp}{Adj}=\frac{9000}{GC}$... This gives you the same length for $GC$.

Comment: But the side of GC is not known. Neither is the side of PC. Why did we not use PC aswell?

Comment: The question is asking you to find the ground, so find the length $GC$. This is our unknown. Pick an corner - they chose $P$. Then form your equation using the corresponding angle, $55^{\circ}$. You know the $Opp$ here, and you want to find $Adj$, so you go for $\tan$...

Comment: Thank you that makes logical sense. Have a good day.